# Is it possible to view a list of all resources with a specific permission?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I would like to quickly identify where a specific permission is applied across my whole GCP estate. For example I would like to know what resources are configured with the permission iam.serviceAccounts.actAs

Is there a command for this?

Answer (score 2):

No. You will need to check: 1) IAM in each project. 2) Every resource in your Google Project that supports identity (Compute Engine, Cloud Functions, etc.). 3) Each organization and folder as roles can be inherited. 4) Each Cloud Storage object also supports identity but not `actAs`.

The design of Google Cloud does not make this task easy nor bulletproof.